# check if option exists in the cart already php

Tags: php, laravel, loops, session, foreach

I am trying to see if the option selected already exists in the session. So i created a foreach loop to go throw all the options in the session and do an if statement on it. My issue is that the if statement 1/5 fails for me randomly when it should pass everytime there are options that exist in the session. The request is always correct as it is coming from the DOM. So the issue lies in my foreach loop

PHP

```
foreach(Session::get('cartitems') as $items => $value) {
    if(isset($value['options']) && $value['options'] == implode('', $request->options)) {
        Session::forget('cartitems.'.$key);
    }
}
```

My object session object looks like this

```
{  
   "3":{  
      "product_id":"1",
      "qty":2,
      "options":"5"
   },
   "4":{  
      "product_id":"1",
      "qty":2,
      "options":"1"
   },
   "5":{  
      "product_id":"1",
      "qty":3,
      "options":"3"
   },
   "6":{  
      "product_id":"1",
      "qty":3,
      "options":"1"
   }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more information this code is incomplete, the $key variable isn't set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check the session already excited in option, I recommend use "nested foreach" then you can loop all value to check, hope it can help

```
foreach(Session::get('cartitems') as cartitem_key => $cartitem_row) { //session array

   foreach($request->options as option_key => option_row){ //option array

      if($cartime_row['options'] == option_row['options']){

         Session::forget('cartitems[$cartitem_key]);

      }

   }

}
```